# I am unable to connect to a WPA2 Enterprise authenticated WiFi access point. What could be wrong?

Tags: wireless, networking

I have entered correct credentials, but am unable to connect to my WiFi access point or router. The WPA Gui displays an attempt to connect, remains in that state for a while, but disconnects without ever having received an IP address over the DHCP.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You need to provide much more detail. What happens when you try to connect and what are you doing to attempt the connection in the first place?

Comment: @recantha - How is the current edit?

Answer (score 2):

Certain WiFi communication (WPA2-enterprise) uses time-stamped cryptographic techniques to secure communication against replay attacks. If the time on your raspberry pi is different from the time on the authentication server, the authentication will fail.

The solution is to manually update the time or use `sudo ntpdate <some ntp server>` while connected to via the ethernet.

Comment: Very unlikely to be this. Consider a more obvious answer to a broad question.

Comment: I put this up because I a 2 more of my friends had trouble connecting on the WPA2-Enterprise WiFi at the university. Fixing the time over the Ethernet got us logged on.

Comment: Is the OP using WPA2-enterprise?  @LordLoh are you answering your own question?  If you are to document the problem that your friends experienced, you should put WPA2-Enterprise into the question as what is being used.

Comment: @LordLoh. Thx for the answer, we had exactly the same problem. The pie has no clock itself so we couldn't start to connect to the enterprise wpa, however we hacked it with a shell script to set the time manually, wonder how long it gonna last [;:

Answer (score 2):

Apart from inadequate power supply, you should also try WICD to make configuration easier and error free. Also, have a look here - http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=18907&p=193700

Answer (score 0):

Test your voltage on the Pi.  I suspect your power supply is inadequate.

Comment: I was using a 30A power supply - An ATX SMPS.

Comment: That seems to eliminate that...